# How to flatten my data from nested references?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, performance, data-structures

Hey guys I need some help to structure some data, but I would need some insights to do this as performant as possible. I have been losing my head with recursions and multiple loops. I have simplified the data to understand the concept and solve it my self with your insights.
I have:

```js
const data = [
{
   id: 'W1', 
   color: red,
   personId: 'P77',
},
{
   id: 'W7', 
   color: yellow,
   personId: 'P21',
},
]

const persons = [
{
   id: 'P77',
   name: 'Peter',
   favoriteFoodId: 'FF4',
},
{
   id: 'P21',
   name: 'John',
   favoriteFood: 'FF9',
}
];

const favoriteFood = [
{
   id: 'FF9'
   food: 'pasta'
  description: 'fresh italian pasta from stone oven'
},
{
   id: 'FF4'
   food: 'banana'
  description: 'fresh bananas from the tree'
}
]
```

How do I merge in the data to be flattened with all its references? How do I make this generic enough to handle deep nesting to flatten it and pick up the references? I tried this, but I was just looping too much that it didn't look sane anymore.

I would like to get a result like this:

```js
const result  = [
{
   id: 'W1', 
   color: red,
   name: 'Peter',
  food: 'banana'
  description: 'fresh bananas from the tree'
},
{
   id: 'W7', 
   color: yellow,
   name: 'Peter',
    food: 'pasta'
   description: 'fresh italian pasta from stone oven'
},
]
```

And `result` would be passed to my table component that will render each object as a row

Comment: Show us what you've tried so we can help you understand where you might be going wrong.

Comment: I only have it with real data, I can share a snippet of that if you'd like, but the data there goes much deeper.

Comment: So my thought process was like will write a function which accepts 4 params, what the function does is something like at a time arr1, arr2, arr1Key, arr2Key. so we will merge this array. Since we need to do recursively we can't execute the function by passing explicitly the keys every time, so what we can do is construct an object and that object will have the keys like when data and persons are going to the function it should take personId and id now when function executes it will give the combined data. So the output again we will pass it as arr1 and take the next array.so somewhat like this

Comment: Let me know if there is any h case is there from ur question perspective if we try to follow this approach

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS That's indeed what I was trying, but I wasn't able to succeed. Would you be a able to provide an answer with an example of this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered Dictionaries?

```js
const data = 
{
   'W1':{ color: "red" ,  personId: 'P77' }
   ,'W7':{ color: "yellow", personId: 'P21'},
}

const persons =
{
  'P77':{ name: 'Peter', favoriteFoodId: 'FF4' },
   'P21':{ name: 'John', favoriteFoodId: 'FF9' } 
}

const favoriteFoods = 
{
   'FF9':{ food: 'pasta', description: 'fresh italian pasta from stone oven' }
  ,'FF4':{ food: 'banana', description: 'fresh bananas from the tree' }
}

function getFavFood( pId , field ){
  return favoriteFoods[ persons[ data[pId].personId ].favoriteFoodId ][field]
}

// not sure what template library you'll be using
// but for now plain old js....

table = "<TABLE>"

for( d in data){
  table += `<TR style="background:${data[d].color}">`
  + `<TD>${ persons[ data[d].personId ].name }</TD>`
  + `<TD>${ getFavFood( d , "food" ) }</TD>`
  + `<TD>${ getFavFood( d , "description" ) }</TD>`
  +`</TR>` 
}

table += "</TABLE>"

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( "beforeend" , table )
```

Comment: How would this work from `persons` perspective then? Doing `console.log( favoriteFoods['FF9'].food )` makes sense, but how do I look it up from person?

Comment: Amended example, it does get complex as you go deeper, but you can always abstract away the complexity into a get method...